# How to adjust the LinearLayout elements when the layout children don't fit?

Tags: java, android

So for example I have these buttons which are as follows:

```
| [button1] [button2]     |
| [button3] [button4]     |
```

But when I add more buttons, they don't fit and look like:

```
| [button1] [button2]     |
| [button3] [button4] [but|
```

As the result, it scrolls horizontally.

I have tried using `LayoutParams` for the layout weight but instead I made some buttons stretched out and some buttons smaller, and it eliminates the gap between the buttons. I also have tried `ButtonBarLayout` but it changed the orientation of the buttons which is completely different than what I wanted.

Here is my attempt which always weights the elements regardless if they fit or not

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
     super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, (int) Utils.dp(getResources(), 96));
     params.weight = 1F;

     int childCount = this.getChildCount();
     for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
         View view = this.getChildAt(i);
         view.setLayoutParams(params);
     }
}
```

And this is the XML (the button row that's too long to fit):

```
<com.tb24.fn.view.LockerRowLayout
    android:id="@+id/locker_wrap_slots"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/locker_slot_wrap1"
        layout="@layout/slot_view" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/locker_slot_wrap2"
        layout="@layout/slot_view" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/locker_slot_wrap3"
        layout="@layout/slot_view" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/locker_slot_wrap4"
        layout="@layout/slot_view" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/locker_slot_wrap5"
        layout="@layout/slot_view" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/locker_slot_wrap6"
        layout="@layout/slot_view" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/locker_slot_wrap7"
        layout="@layout/slot_view" />
</com.tb24.fn.view.LockerRowLayout>
```

The `LockerRowLayout` class extends `LinearLayout`.

So in the example, I want to let the layout adjust the second row buttons, but let the first row be intact. I don't want to make it scroll and instead I want to make their widths smaller and truncate them dynamically, for example:

```
| [button1] [button2]     |
| [but.1] [but.2] [but.3] |
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the dynamic width programmatically, rather you can use `android:layout_weight="1"` and `android:layout_width="0dp"` in all the buttons inside a row in your xml which should automatically size them equally to fit the entire width altogether (I mean no overflow).